# Angular 2+ Can you add/remove a CSS class based on html data property?

Tags: angular, attr, ng-class

First I would like to add a little more context to the question.

Right now I have the following:

- A list item that contains [another list that floats right next to it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXkv8.png)
- At the moment I'm showing and hiding the element based on a property from the class using the mouseover/out events

I want to make it more dynamic by removing the need to have a property in the class and just add a data property to the html element, in hopes that I can manage it's state using said property.

This whole idea might be wrong, so if there is another way to achieve this, please guide me into the right direction.

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

After some thinking I changed my approach a bit, instead of relying on the component property I added to each element a new [attr.data-visible] property with a default "false" value. Then on the mouseover event I added a method that gets the html element as a parameter and then changes the data-visible value from false to true, and vice versa on the mouseout event.

[Here is a working StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-i62hzm?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hzdmzg?file=src/app/app.component.ts)   you can do it with ngClass and events.

```
 [ngClass]="{'your_class': isHovered}"
 (mouseover)="isHovered=true"
 (mouseout)="isHovered=false"
```

If you have an array object and do it inside them then give property to each object in array

```
 [ngClass]="{'your_class': data.isHovered}"
    (mouseover)="data.isHovered=true"
    (mouseout)="data.isHovered=false"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm wondering where does isHovered coming from? Is it some default angular/html property or is it a class property?

Comment: if you have one element create one property in component as isHovered as boolean ,if your have array object add one more attribute for this. This is created by you to assign to class

Comment: Because right now I am using a class property, and that's what I'm trying to avoid. Because for example if I have 10 ui elements, it gets pretty messy having 10 bool properties inside my class just to show/hide this lists.

Comment: Okey as I said if you have list element then give property for each object in list . I will put demo now

Comment: I added demo  now to answer

Comment: Thank you for the demo, but its not really what i had in mind. My html elements are not created dynamically, so I would have to add a new property for each element in the app.component.ts so i can show/hide the floating list. (this is what i am doing currently) 
Right now i want to try to use the [attr.data-something] as a way to do this without having properties in app.component.ts

Comment: If you put demo code in stackblitz I can understand better

Comment: I think i figured it out. I will edit the question with the solution i came up with

Answer (score 0):

You can add/remove a class using the following syntax:

```html
<div [class.your-class-name]="condition"></div>
```

In order to reference an element without the need of the component you can use [Template Reference Variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables) as follows:

```html
<div #abc></div>
```

Now `abc` can be used in your template to reference it's div element

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I realized I'm bad at explaining my issue. I updated the question and added the solution to the problem.